# SQL Combine Two Columns in Select Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

If I have a column that is Address1 and Address2 in my database, how do I combine those columns so that I could perform operations on it only in my select statement,  I will still leave them separate in the database. I would like to be able to do this

```
WHERE completeaddress LIKE '%searchstring%'
```

Where completedaddress is the combination of Address1 and Address2. searchstring would be like the data they searched for. So if they had '123 Center St' in Address1 and 'Apt 3B' in Address2, how would I have it select it if the searchstring was 'Center St 3B' Is this possible with SQL?

Comment: You would need to look into full text indexing for this. the concatenated result would be `'123 Center St Apt 3B'` which doesn't match `Center St 3B`

Comment: But it would sound like it, if using `SOUNDEX` as per my answer below.

Comment: @anothershrubery - I used `soundex` once in a real world application and ended up removing it as the results were bizarre and no one understood them. `select SOUNDEX('123 Center St Apt 3B'),SOUNDEX('Center St 3B')` returns `0000,C536`

Comment: Yeah it can be a bit weird, but is the closest way possible to perform like atrljoe wants. You can do various other manipulations of the `SOUNDEX` string, or use substrings, to get a greater accuracy.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for -

```
select Address1+Address2 as CompleteAddress from YourTable
where Address1+Address2 like '%YourSearchString%'
```

To prevent a compound word being created when we append address1 with address2, you can use this -

```
select Address1 + ' ' + Address2 as CompleteAddress from YourTable 
where Address1 + ' ' + Address2 like '%YourSearchString%'
```

So, '123 Center St' and 'Apt 3B' will not be '123 Center StApt 3B' but will be '123 Center St Apt 3B'.

Comment: I wish everyone answering this question would stop appending the two columns together - you rarely, if ever, want to create a new hybrid word from the last word in address1 and the first word in address2 - you might want to put a space in between.

Comment: @atrljoe - I am not sure how will this search for the string 'Center St 3B' as given in the question by you?

Comment: @BharatDodeja In PostgreSQL either + is not working. Error: operator doesn't exist. ||Works fine!!! Thanks!

Comment: How would you do this if you didn't know then number of address fields before hand or if different rows had different numbers of address fields filled out?

Comment: I tried `SELECT 'Hello, ' + firstname FROM users` and I got the column name as `'Hello, ' + firstname` and for each user, I got a value of 0...

Comment: This answer didn't work as expected for me. I used CONCAT instead in the SELECT part of the statement like @anothershrubery said

Answer (score 16):

In MySQL you can use:

```
SELECT CONCAT(Address1, " ", Address2)
WHERE SOUNDEX(CONCAT(Address1, " ", Address2)) = SOUNDEX("Center St 3B")
```

The `SOUNDEX` function works similarly in most database systems, I can't think of the syntax for MSSQL at the minute, but it wouldn't be too far away from the above.

Comment: There is no CONCAT in sql server though. Will only work in MySQL

Answer (score 2):

If your `address1 = '123 Center St'` and `address2 = 'Apt 3B'` then even if you combine and do a `LIKE`, you cannot search on searchstring as `'Center St 3B'`. However, if your searchstring was `'Center St Apt'`, then you can do it using -

```
WHERE (address1 + ' ' + address2) LIKE '%searchstring%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT StaffId,(Title+''+FirstName+''+LastName) AS FullName 
FROM StaffInformation
```

Where do you write with in the brackets this will be appear in the one single column. 
Where do you want a dot into the middle of the Title and First Name write syntax below,

```
SELECT StaffId,(Title+'.'+FirstName+''+LastName) AS FullName 
FROM StaffInformation
```

These syntax works with MS SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your database schema (and I would not for this simple query) you can just combine them in the filter like this:
   `WHERE (Address1 + Address2) LIKE '%searchstring%'`