# how to use concat function in ms sql where condition with like

Tags: sql-server, sql-like, trim, concatenation

I have got right output using this below query in `Oracle`.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM MSS WHERE TRIM(UPPER(FIRSTNAME)|| UPPER(SECONDNAME)) LIKE UPPER('qw1')||UPPER('121212')
```

However I need the query for `MS SQL Server`, any help would be appreciated..

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Combine Two Columns in Select Statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247381/sql-combine-two-columns-in-select-statement)

Comment: @bummi all the answers for that question are terrible anyway

Comment: @t-clausen.dk maybe adding a good answer to the linked question might be an alternative.

Comment: @bummi the answer i would give for the linked question is not the same as the answer I would give for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.when creating the table MSS, make sure case sensivity is off on names(collation) and
make sure you use varchar or nvarchar for names.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE MSS
(
firstname nvarchar(50) collate Latin1_General_CI_AS,
lastname nvarchar(50) collate Latin1_General_CI_AS
)
```

2.when populating the table MSS make sure there are no spaces before the name.

Example:

```
declare @val1 nvarchar(50) = ' qw1 '
declare @val2 nvarchar(50) = ' 121212 '
insert MSS(firstname, lastname)
values(ltrim(@val1), ltrim(@val2))
```

3.make a update query to fix current data so the names are not starting with spaces.

Example:

```
UPDATE MSS
SET FIRSTNAME = LTRIM(FIRSTNAME),
SECONDNAME = LTRIM(SECONDNAME)
WHERE FIRSTNAME <> LTRIM(FIRSTNAME)
or SECONDNAME <> LTRIM(SECONDNAME)
```

4.write your query.

Example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT 
FROM MSS
WHERE FIRSTNAME like 'qw1'
and SECONDNAME like '121212'
```

Please stop concating columns before comparing, it slows performance

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM MSS WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(FIRSTNAME) + UPPER(SECONDNAME))) LIKE UPPER('qw1') + UPPER('121212')
```

But I'm not sure if you don't need to compare for anything containg your like condition:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM MSS WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(FIRSTNAME) + UPPER(SECONDNAME))) LIKE '%' + UPPER('qw1') + UPPER('121212') + '%'
```

Otherwise you could just use `=` in your first query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT FROM MSS WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(FIRSTNAME) + UPPER(SECONDNAME))) = UPPER('qw1') + UPPER('121212')
```