# how to convert pipe symbol '||' into mssql

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM ABCD
WHERE TRIM(UPPER(FIRSTNAME)||UPPER(SECONDNAME)) LIKE UPPER('aa')||UPPER('aaa')
```

I need to convert the above query into MSSQL. Please Help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Combine Two Columns in Select Statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247381/sql-combine-two-columns-in-select-statement)

Comment: Did you mean that either `firstname` or `secondname` consists either `aa` or `aaa`? If yes, check my answer, I think it would be appropriate

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to concatenate. Use the + operator or the CONCAT function.

```
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(FIRSTNAME) + UPPER(SECONDNAME))) LIKE '%' + UPPER('aa') + UPPER('aaa') + '%'

WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(CONCAT(UPPER(FIRSTNAME), UPPER(SECONDNAME)))) LIKE CONCAT('%', UPPER('aa'), UPPER('aaa'), '%')
```

Comment: Oops, thanks, @veljasije! Did not realize thee were two and only corrected the first one.

Comment: But your logic seems to be `'PeterPan' LIKE 'aaaaa'`, if I correctly realize your query. I think he need to examine both of columns consist either 'aa' or 'aaa'. By example, your query will not satisfy next example: `FirstName=Petaar` and `SecondName=Paaan`

Comment: Interesting @veljasije. I'm reading it as he needs to test if the concatenation of the value of two fields is like the concatenation of the two strings. Help, user2829965. Which interpretation. Sounds like could be eitehr one and the syntax would be very different.

Comment: Still incorrect syntax :) SQL Server doesn't recognize TRIM as buil-in function, USE RTRIM and LTRIM

Comment: Thanks, @veljasije. Trying to do this during a meeting so wining a bit. Wish could share credit. Am at least upvoting your comments.

Comment: Still you have an errors :) In first query, you have an extra `)` sign before `LIKE`. In second query, same thing, extra sign `)` before `LIKE` clause

Comment: Now we only can wait to solve initial problem, which answer is adequate :)

Answer (score 0):

Right syntax would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM Production.Categories
WHERE (LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(FIRSTNAME))) LIKE '%' + UPPER('aa') + '%'
    OR LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(FIRSTNAME))) LIKE '%' + UPPER('aaa') + '%')
OR
  (LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(SECONDNAME))) LIKE '%' + UPPER('aa') + '%'
    OR LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(SECONDNAME))) LIKE '%' + UPPER('aaa') + '%'))
```

But, when your firstname or secondname consist 'aaa', then for sure consist either an 'aa', so your query will be satisfied if you write it like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM Production.Categories
WHERE 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(FIRSTNAME))) LIKE '%' + UPPER('aa') + '%'
OR
    LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(SECONDNAME))) LIKE '%' + UPPER('aa') + '%'
```