# How to combine fields in datagridview from Sql field names in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I have a DatagridView control that has 4 columns.

[image: datagridview with 4 columns]

I want the `FirstName`, `MiddleName` and `LastName` to be merged and call it as `FullName`.

Like this :

[image: FullName]

My codes as of now is :

```
    public void Data()
    {
        _da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        _da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
        _da.Fill(_dt);
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = _dt;
        PresDG.DataSource = bs;
        _da.Update(_dt);
    }

    private void President()
    {
        sc.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TableVote WHERE Position='President'", sc);

        try
        {
            Data();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sc.Close();
        }
    }
```

How do I do it in my Sql Statement? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247381/sql-combine-two-columns-in-select-statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FirstName+' '+MiddleName+' '+LastName as FullName,VCount FROM TableVote WHERE Position='President'", sc);
```

Comment: You may have problems if any if the fields are Null. Something like this may work for you: COALESCE (First_Name + ' ', '') + COALESCE (Last_Name, '') AS FullName