# How to concatenate two column values in MS SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

I am querying an MS SQL Server database from PHP.  The query works, but when I try inserting a space between the first_name and last_name fields I get an error.

The query works when I write it like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT meetings.name as Subject, 
                 meetings.date_entered, 
                 meetings.date_modified,
                 SELECT (users.first_name + users.last_name) as Fullname FROM dbo.users WHERE users.id = meetings.assigned_user_id';
if($custom_join) {
    $query .= $custom_join['select'];
}
$query .= ' FROM meetings ';
```

However, it fails when I write I try to put a space between the first and last names, like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT meetings.name as Subject, 
                 meetings.date_entered, 
                 meetings.date_modified,
                 SELECT (users.first_name + ' ' + users.last_name) as Fullname    FROM dbo.users WHERE users.id = meetings.assigned_user_id';
if($custom_join) {
    $query .= $custom_join['select'];
}
$query .= ' FROM meetings ';
```

The error I get is that '' is not a valid column in SQL table or something like that.

Also the Fullname which i use as (Fullname) comes in as small letter :--> fullname. Why is that the uppercase 'F' turns into lowercase 'f'?

I have mainly worked on MySQL, but I am fairly new to MS SQL ...its a bit weird. Even the Concat function does not work here. When I try to use that, it tells me that it is not a built-in function.

**Edit:**

```
$query = 'SELECT meetings.name as Subject, 
                 meetings.date_entered, 
                 meetings.date_modified,
                 (SELECT (users.first_name + ' ' + users.last_name) as Fullname    
                          FROM dbo.users WHERE users.id = meetings.assigned_user_id)';
```

**Edit 2:**

```
$query = 'SELECT meetings.name as Subject, 
                 meetings.date_entered, 
                 meetings.date_modified,
                 SELECT (users.first_name + '' '' + users.last_name) as Fullname
                         FROM dbo.users WHERE users.id = meetings.assigned_user_id';
if($custom_join) {
    $query .= $custom_join['select'];
}
$query .= ' FROM meetings ';
```

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247381/sql-combine-two-columns-in-select-statement` this might help u

Comment: yes i saw that link but i need to put a space between the first name and last name bro.

Comment: `SELECT (users.first_name + ' ' + users.last_name) as Fullname 
  FROM dbo.users WHERE users.id = meetings.assigned_user_id` - try using this one

Comment: [I can't reproduce this error](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20290/1). Are you definitely using single quotes and not double quotes? CONCAT is a built in function in SQL Server 2012, but not in earlier versions.

Comment: @Prava it does not work..Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Sql Server do you use ?

Comment: Obviously, you're not running this query in SQL Server Management Studio.  The issue is not your query, but how you're executing it.  See my answer below where I have put together a SQL Fiddle example of the problem which executes quite well in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: The query is invalid. The initial error is because using single quotes in single quotes string. do $query = "...sql query with ' and '..."

Answer (score 1):

You've left a space out of your string constant.

Instead of `''`, use `' '`.

Please see this SQLFiddle of the issue:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cde45/1)

Comment: nope it dont work as well : --->(SELECT (users.first_name+  ' ' +users.last_name) as Fullname  FROM dbo.users WHERE users.id = meetings.assigned_user_id)

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus, Perhaps he used a double-quote and mistyped his question here.  There's not enough information given to explain the error he saw, however, there is enough information given to determine that his query is incorrect.

Comment: @user3054077, please provide the error message you see.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you use the CONCAT function?

```
SELECT CONCAT(users.first_name, SPACE(1) ,users.last_name) AS Result  FROM dbo.users WHERE users.id = meetings.assigned_user_id
```

Comment: it says it not a builtin function i use older version sql 2008

Answer (score 1):

From context it seems likely that you're not running this exact query in SSMS, so you're likely missing extra single quotes needed to escape the single quotes you want to leave:

```
(SELECT users.first_name + '' '' +users.last_name as Fullname)
```

Update: I see from your question update that I was correct, but you've also got an invalid query, no second `FROM` clause, hard to tell exactly what you're after, but perhaps:

```
$query = 'SELECT meetings.name as Subject, 
                  meetings.date_entered, 
                  meetings.date_modified,
                  users.first_name + '' '' + users.last_name as Fullname    
          FROM dbo.users 
          JOIN dbo.meetings
             ON users.id = meetings.assigned_user_id)
              ';
```

Comment: Your edit shows an invalid query with only one `FROM` clause but referencing 2 tables and no `JOIN`. I've taken a guess at what you're actually after in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with concatenation anymore, it is a malformed SQL query. The concatenation issue was caused by single quotes in single quoted string.

The following code should return a valid query:

```
$query = "SELECT meetings.name as Subject, 
            meetings.date_entered, 
            meetings.date_modified,
            (SELECT users.first_name + ' ' + users.last_name 
            FROM dbo.users WHERE users.id = meetings.assigned_user_id
            ) as Fullname 
        ";
        //$query = 'SELECT meetings.*';

        if($custom_join) {
            $query .= $custom_join['select'];
        }
        $query .= " FROM meetings ";
```

This is how the query will look like:

```
$query = "SELECT meetings.name as Subject, 
                meetings.date_entered, 
                meetings.date_modified,
                (SELECT users.first_name + ' ' + users.last_name) 
                FROM dbo.users WHERE users.id = meetings.assigned_user_id
                ) as Fullname
                FROM meetings";
```

Comment: if i remove this : ---> + '' '' +    it works but then the first name and second name sticks together

Comment: You are confusing two single quotes '' and one double quote ". I have 4 single quotes here.... single quote single quote space single quote single quote

Comment: SELECT (users.first_name +'' ''+ users.last_name) as Fullname  FROM dbo.users

Comment: try-->$query="SELECT (users.first_name +' '+ users.last_name) as Fullname FROM dbo.users". Here I have the whole query in double quotes a concatenation with only 2 single quotes.

Comment: u mean this -- >   "SELECT (users.first_name +' '+ users.last_name) as Fullname FROM dbo.users
   WHERE users.id = meetings.assigned_user_id "